# how I can cancel the value of the entire instruction

Tags: javascript

```
let mood = 'sleepy';
let tirednessLevel = 6;

if (mood === 'sleepy' || tirednessLevel > 8) {
  console.log('time to sleep');
} else {
  console.log('not bed time yet');
}
```

How I can cancel the value of the entire instruction with!  ??

Comment: put code in code tag and give us more verbose description of your problem

Comment: i begin javascript tutorial, so i don't know Javascript Tag i'm sorry, it's an exercice one codecademy who ask cancel the value of entire instruction with logical operators !

Comment: Well `!` means NOT, so now you have `if (mood === 'sleepy')` - literally IF mood sleepy do something... If you put NOT operator like this `if (mood !== 'sleepy')` - then it will mean IF mood NOT sleepy then do something.

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you mean by "_cancel the value of entire instruction_". What value? What instruction? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: OR if by ENTIRE instruction you mean this `if (mood === 'sleepy' || tirednessLevel > 8)` then you can reverse it like this `if (!(mood === 'sleepy' || tirednessLevel > 8))`

Comment: oh reaaly cool ! thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ivar, value= 'sleepy', instruction = if (mood === 'sleepy' || tirednessLevel > 8), i'm sorry for unclear i'm really beginner and i'm french ^^' . I talk about the "logical operators exercice on codecademy"

Answer (score 0):

Need More Info about what you want but this may help you to know

```js
let mood = 'sleepy';
let tirednessLevel = 6;
function check() {    
  if (mood=== 'sleepy' || tirednessLevel > 8){    
      return 'time to sleep';    
  } else{    
      return 'not bed time yet'; 
  }
  return '';
}
console.log(check())
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I have not yet touched on the subject of functions.